# LN word problem

Tags: calculus, logarithms, applications

measurement of a child's ability to learn is given by the function
$$L(t)=\frac{ln(t+1)}{t+1}$$ where t is the child's age in years, for $0 ≤ t ≤ 5$

At what age does a child have the greatest learning ability?

At what age is a child's learning ability increasing most rapidly?

Honestly, I'm not even sure where to start, should I take the 2nd derivative?

Comment: HInt: take the first derivative first, get the maximum.  That isn't too bad.  Then use the second derivative to find the max for the first derivative.

Comment: (1-ln(t+1))/((t+1)^2). I'm not understanding what you mean by, get the maximum after taking the first derivative. I've got the first derivative, should I plug in 5 to t?

Comment: Once you have the first derivative (which I see you do) then you just need to set to to 0 to find the max.  Well, you should check the endpoints as well (that's a hint for the second part).

Comment: second derivative set to zero: 0 = 2ln(t+1)=-3 :: 2ln(t+2)=3 :: t = e^(3/2)-1 :: t = 3.4.., I think, I've done it? is that it? thank you all of the support

Comment: Be careful!  The second derivative part is sneaky.  the time of maximal increase can't be greater than the max of the function (you found the time of maximal decrease!).  This is where the endpoint hint comes into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. At what age does a child have the greatest learning abilit [sic.] ?

The child's ability to learn is measured by the function, so the first question asks when that ability is maximal, or when the function attains its maximum value. That is done by taking the first derivative and performing the first derivative test, and also testing at the endpoints, like so:

$$ L(t) = \frac{ln(t + 1)}{t + 1} $$
$$ L'(t) = \frac{1 - ln(t + 1)}{(t+1)^2} $$

Solving for the critical numbers only requires checking the numerator and denominator separately, since if either is 0 there will be an undefined or zero value for the function, either way a critical number.

$ 1 - ln(t + 1) = 0 $ attains a zero where the natural log 1 equals 1, so at e - 1 or about 1.71828

$ (t+1)^2 = 0 $ has no solutions on the domain $ 0 \leq t \leq 5 $

So which is the maximum? We simply check the values and receive x = 1.71828 as our maximum.

L(0) = 0
L(1.71828) = 0.36788
L(5) = 0.29863

Therefore, the child has the greatest learning ability at about 1.71828 years of age.

### 2. At what age is a child's learning ability increasing most rapidly?

The *rate of change of the increase* of the function is a rate of change of a rate of change: simply find where the first derivative attains its maximum, by using the first derivative test on the first derivative. That means you do have to find the second derivative as you assumed, and do the same test I demonstrated on that. Although it might be a bit longer, the concept isn't any trickier so I leave it to you. Be sure to check the endpoints!